# Why does `arrayUnion` in Firestore sends all values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, optimization

I was hoping I could reduce the cost of my application trying to optimize different parts of it.

So I tried to use `arrayUnion` in all places that see fit.
Problem is when I opened the network console to monitor the changes I realized it didn't change anything. In fact `arrayUnion` seems to be sending all the field values over the network anyways.

So my question is what's the real use of using `arrayUnion` in one's app if the result in the background is the same?

Comment: Are you performing the query on the client (iOS, Android, or web) or using the admin SDK?

Comment: Hi does my posted answer help ? If so acknowledge it if not then we can solve it further.

Answer (score 1):

> when I opened the network console to monitor the changes I realized it didn't change anything. In fact arrayUnion seems to be sending all the field values over the network anyways.

This is because Firestore updates are sent over the network as complete documents. This is the indented behavior whether you use [**arrayUnion()**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) or not. However, the actual update applied on the server side is an atomic operation(Transaction) that ensures only unique elements are added to the array.

> What's the real use of using arrayUnion in one's app if the result in the background is the same?

The benefit of using `arrayUnion()` is that it provides an atomic operation, meaning that the update is applied as a single, indivisible operation. This ensures that multiple concurrent updates to the same document do not result in conflicting changes. And the syntax is just an ease of doing that thing elegantly.

You can even see in the comments of the [**Update elements in an array**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) code snippet like

```js
// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field. ⇐ 
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    regions: arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});
```

If we don’t use `arrayUnion()`, then you would need to fetch the document, modify the array locally, and then update the document with the modified array. This could lead to race conditions and inconsistent data if multiple clients are updating the array simultaneously.

There is also a article written specifying it by `QuintoAndar Tech Blog Lucca La Fonte Albuquerque Carvalho`by the name : [**Race Conditions in Firestore: How to Solve it ?**](https://medium.com/quintoandar-tech-blog/race-conditions-in-firestore-how-to-solve-it-5d6ff9e69ba7)